# git review, command shows so many outstanding commits , which are not mine

Tags: git, gerrit

"You are about to submit multiple commits. This is expected if you are
submitting a commit that is dependent on one or more in-review
commits. Otherwise you should consider squashing your changes into one
commit before submitting."

this is the message i get when i do git review,but i have checked out from latest master on to this brnach and made my changes but still this message pops up and lists so many  commits which are not mine for review submission, can anyone please explain why does it appear , and please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Check again: 1) git fetch 2) git log <commit-you-want-push> 3) git log origin/master 4) compare the SHA (not the commit message) of the first 5 commits. I think there's some different commit.

Comment: Did you do git fetch gerrit first?